# Issue with window keyword in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, window, partition

I am not able to understand the issue with this query written 'Oracle sql developer' Tool.

```
SELECT 
MAX(DOC_CRCY_CD) OVER(UNQTXGRP),MIN(DOC_CRCY_CD) OVER(UNQTXGRP)
FROM
ord_dtl
WINDOW UNQTXGRP AS (PARTITION BY QTA_PROD_LN_ID,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORD_CRT_DT,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,PROD_ID,FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD)
```

When I run this query I am getting the following error

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 2 Column: 23

Comment: there is no `window` clause in Oracle 11g. you have to specify it in `over`.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Thanks..Is there a way with which we can reuse the partitioning.

Comment: You need to type it out again for each analytic function

Comment: Please specify the source data/tables and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I think oracle don't know window keyword.
You must define window in each over definition.

```
SELECT 
MAX(DOC_CRCY_CD) OVER(PARTITION BY QTA_PROD_LN_ID,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORD_CRT_DT,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,PROD_ID,FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD)
,MIN(DOC_CRCY_CD) OVER(PARTITION BY QTA_PROD_LN_ID,OM_SRC_SYS_KY,SO_ID,SRC_SYS_KY,ORD_CRT_DT,BUS_AREA_CD,SO_LN_ITM_ID,PROD_ID,FDW_TRAN_TYPE_CD)
FROM
ord_dtl;
```